# Parse XML to CSV using Python nonetype error

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse XML file to CSV. However, I am getting the following error.
I have tested the logic with another simple XML and it seems to work. I have provided below my error, the XML file, the python code, and my desired output. Right now I have only added two of my columns. Have been looking at this for hours so another set of eyes would be much appreciated. Thank you!

**Error:**

```
name = member.find('CaseName').tag AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

**XML File:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Nuix version="7.2.2" architecture="amd64">
  <Export
    startTime="Sun Feb 25 22:07:07 2018 (America/Chicago)"
    endTime="Sun Feb 25 22:08:03 2018 (America/Chicago)"
    exportDuration="55s"
    processingDuration="55s">

    <ExportConfiguration>

      <LoadFiles>
      </LoadFiles>

      <MessageFormat>NATIVE</MessageFormat>
      <ExportDirectory>C:\Users\KK132WQ\Desktop\Brooklyn Case - Nuix\OCR cache directory</ExportDirectory>
      <SeparateEmailAttachments>false</SeparateEmailAttachments>
      <RegenerateNatives>false</RegenerateNatives>
      <RegeneratePdfs>false</RegeneratePdfs>
      <FindTopLevelItems>false</FindTopLevelItems>
      <DescendantItems>false</DescendantItems>
      <ExportContainers>false</ExportContainers>
      <SortOrder>position</SortOrder>

      <CaseName>Brooklyn</CaseName>
      <CaseLocation>C:\Users\KK132WQ\Desktop\Brooklyn Case - Nuix</CaseLocation>

      <TimeZone>America/Chicago</TimeZone>


      <Numbering>
        <Strategy>Document ID numbering</Strategy>
        <DocumentPagesInSameFolder>true</DocumentPagesInSameFolder>
        <FamilyDocumentsInSameFolder>false</FamilyDocumentsInSameFolder>
        <FirstItemNumber>DOC-000000001</FirstItemNumber>
      </Numbering>

      <Imaging>
        <ImagingProfile>Default</ImagingProfile>
      </Imaging>

      <Naming>
        <NativeNamingScheme>Page only</NativeNamingScheme>
        <PdfNamingScheme>Page only</PdfNamingScheme>
      </Naming>
      <OcrSettings>
          <Recognition>High Quality - Slow</Recognition>
          <Deskewed/>
          <UpdateTextStore append="true"/>
          <Rotation>Auto</Rotation>
          <Languages>English</Languages>
      </OcrSettings>

      <ResemblanceThreshold>0.85</ResemblanceThreshold>

    </ExportConfiguration>

    <ExportStatistics>
      <SelectedItems>4</SelectedItems>
      <ExcludedCount>0</ExcludedCount>
      <TotalItemsToExport>4</TotalItemsToExport>
      <FailedItems>0</FailedItems>
      <DocumentNumbers>
        <First></First>
        <Last></Last>
      </DocumentNumbers>
    </ExportStatistics>

    <ExportStageDetails>
      <Stage
        name="WORK_QUEUE"
        successfulItems="4"
        failedItems="0"
        duration="1s">

        <SlipsheetItemDetails>
        </SlipsheetItemDetails>

        <FailedItemDetails>
        </FailedItemDetails>
      </Stage>
      <Stage
        name="NATIVE"
        successfulItems="4"
        failedItems="0"
        duration="33s">

        <SlipsheetItemDetails>
        </SlipsheetItemDetails>

        <FailedItemDetails>
        </FailedItemDetails>
      </Stage>
      <Stage
        name="STORED_EMAIL_FIXUP"
        successfulItems="4"
        failedItems="0"
        duration="1s">

        <SlipsheetItemDetails>
        </SlipsheetItemDetails>

        <FailedItemDetails>
        </FailedItemDetails>
      </Stage>
      <Stage
        name="PDF"
        successfulItems="4"
        failedItems="0"
        duration="1s">

        <SlipsheetItemDetails>
        </SlipsheetItemDetails>

        <FailedItemDetails>
        </FailedItemDetails>
      </Stage>
      <Stage
        name="BINARY_STORE"
        successfulItems="0"
        failedItems="0"
        duration="0s">

        <SlipsheetItemDetails>
        </SlipsheetItemDetails>

        <FailedItemDetails>
        </FailedItemDetails>
      </Stage>
      <Stage
        name="OCR_INITIALISATION"
        successfulItems="4"
        failedItems="0"
        duration="0s">

        <SlipsheetItemDetails>
        </SlipsheetItemDetails>

        <FailedItemDetails>
        </FailedItemDetails>
      </Stage>
      <Stage
        name="OCR"
        successfulItems="4"
        failedItems="0"
        duration="17s">

        <SlipsheetItemDetails>
        </SlipsheetItemDetails>

        <FailedItemDetails>
        </FailedItemDetails>
      </Stage>
      <Stage
        name="POST_OCR"
        successfulItems="4"
        failedItems="0"
        duration="0s">

        <SlipsheetItemDetails>
        </SlipsheetItemDetails>

        <FailedItemDetails>
        </FailedItemDetails>
      </Stage>
      <Stage
        name="TEXT_REPLACEMENT"
        successfulItems="4"
        failedItems="0"
        duration="1s">

        <SlipsheetItemDetails>
        </SlipsheetItemDetails>

        <FailedItemDetails>
        </FailedItemDetails>
      </Stage>
    </ExportStageDetails>

    <FileStatistics>
      <NativeFilesExported>3</NativeFilesExported>
      <NativeFilesFromStore>0</NativeFilesFromStore>
      <NativeFilesExportedInline>0</NativeFilesExportedInline>
      <NativeFilesExportedParallel>3</NativeFilesExportedParallel>
      <NativeFilesExportedParallelLocal>0</NativeFilesExportedParallelLocal>
      <NativeFilesWithInvalidTimes>0</NativeFilesWithInvalidTimes>
      <NativePlaceHolderFilesExported>0</NativePlaceHolderFilesExported>
      <NativeFilesRegenerated>0</NativeFilesRegenerated>
      <TextFilesExported>0</TextFilesExported>
      <TextPlaceHolderFilesExported>0</TextPlaceHolderFilesExported>
      <PdfFilesExported>0</PdfFilesExported>
      <PdfFilesStamped>0</PdfFilesStamped>
      <TiffFilesExported>0</TiffFilesExported>

      <PdfDetails>
        <PdfFilesFromStore>0</PdfFilesFromStore>
        <PdfFilesRegenerated>0</PdfFilesRegenerated>
        <PdfFilesExportedInline>0</PdfFilesExportedInline>
        <PdfFilesExportedParallel>0</PdfFilesExportedParallel>
        <PdfFilesExportedParallelLocal>0</PdfFilesExportedParallelLocal>
        <UserImportedPdfs>0</UserImportedPdfs>
        <PrintedPdfs>0</PrintedPdfs>
        <UnformattedTextPdfs>0</UnformattedTextPdfs>
        <ItemEncryptedPdfs>0</ItemEncryptedPdfs>
        <UnprintableItemPdfs>0</UnprintableItemPdfs>
      </PdfDetails>
    </FileStatistics>

    <PageCountStatistics>
      <PdfPages>0</PdfPages>
      <StampedPages>0</StampedPages>
      <FailedStampedPages>0</FailedStampedPages>
      <AveragePageCount>0.0</AveragePageCount>
    </PageCountStatistics>

    <ThroughputStatistics>
      <NativeDocRate>0.0857363321997085</NativeDocRate>
      <PdfDocRate>0.0</PdfDocRate>
      <StampedDocRate>0.0</StampedDocRate>
      <PdfPageRate>0.0</PdfPageRate>
      <StampingPageRate>0.0</StampingPageRate>
    </ThroughputStatistics>

    <MimeTypeStatistics>
      <MimeTypes>
        <MimeType name="application/pdf" count="4" />
      </MimeTypes>
    </MimeTypeStatistics>

  </Export>
</Nuix>
```

**Python Code:**

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import csv

    tree = ET.parse('D:\\Users\\eferse\\Desktop\\XML_parsing\\summary-report.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()

    # open a file for writing

    Resident_data = open('D:\\Users\\eferse\\Desktop\\XML_parsing\\Nuix Export XML Parse_PythonOutput.csv', 'w')

    # create the csv writer object

    csvwriter = csv.writer(Resident_data)
    resident_head = []

    count = 0
    for member in root.findall('Export'):
        resident = []
        address_list = []
        if count == 0:
            name = member.find('CaseName').tag
            resident_head.append(CaseName)
            location= member.find('CaseLocation').tag
            resident_head.append(CaseLocation)

            csvwriter.writerow(resident_head)
            count = count + 1

        name = member.find('CaseName').text
        resident.append(CaseName)
        location= member.find('CaseLocation').text
        resident.append(CaseLocation)


        csvwriter.writerow(resident)
    Resident_data.close()
```

**Desired Output:**
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8FHB.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [**minimal**, complete, and verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and add sample input and expected output. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used indexing to access the child elements in question.  Sometimes this is easier to do when you know where the information is.

You can check this using the following

```
for child in root[0]:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

and you can navigate further by continuing the index as far as you like `root[0][0][1]` etc etc

You have to remember that the index is the parent and you are looking for the children.  in your case root is `Nuix` which will return the children in this instance `Export`

`root[0]` is 'Export' which `find` will search the children and return what you want which is `ExportConfiguration` and inside here is what you are looking for `CaseName` and `CaseLocation`..

if you do

```
for child in root[0][0]:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

This will print the tags of `CaseName` etc but you will not be able to use find at this level.  You will be searching inside `CaseName` for `CaseName`.

Once you have the parent you are able to find the children easier.

This code works.

I have taken the empty lists out of the loop.

I have also changed the `append` values as they did not have a variable, only a string name... I have also indented some appends as they were outside of the loop.

I have left the `print` statements in so you can see what is going on.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse('summary-report.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

Resident_data = open('Parse_PythonOutput.csv', 'a')

    # create the csv writer object

csvwriter = csv.writer(Resident_data)
resident_head = []
resident = []
address_list = []

count = 0
for member in root[0]:
    if count == 0:

        name = member.find('CaseName').tag
        print(name)
        resident_head.append(name)

        location = member.find('CaseLocation').tag
        print(location)
        resident_head.append(location)

        csvwriter.writerow(resident_head)
        count = count + 1

        name_text = member.find('CaseName').text
        print(name_text)
        resident.append(name_text)

        text_location = member.find('CaseLocation').text
        print(text_location)
        resident.append(text_location)

        print(resident)

csvwriter.writerow(resident)

Resident_data.close()
```

The CSV data file looks like this:

```
CaseName,CaseLocation
Brooklyn,C:\Users\KK132WQ\Desktop\Brooklyn Case - Nuix
```

Comment: This helped me enormously! thank you for taking the time to explain!

Comment: no problem.. Please select as a correct answer for future users.. the green tick :)